# Copy path to opened file in PL SQL developer

Tags: windows, file, plsql, plsqldeveloper

When I open files in PL SQL developer I want to copy file path so I can go directly to the directory I need.

One way is to hover on the file and wait for tool tip to appear. But I have to wait a few seconds and I am not able to copy the path. Can I know the path in any other way?

[image: path to file on hover]

Comment: click save as to get the directory ?,

Comment: Thank you, havent thought about that :) Kind of possible solution

Comment: no probs, i am doing it that way :)

Comment: See https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/plsqldeveloper-setup-1.html#tools, have a look at "Explore to here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for my exact situation I need to configure custom tool like that:

[image]

So now it opens explorer where it shows the exact folder my file is located in.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Configure > Tools*

*New*

Define a tool as:

- Executable/Script: `cmd`
- Parameters: `/c echo "#path" & pause`
- for the image I picked `Tree View.png` from the default selection.

[image: PL/SQL Developer Tools Configuration]

The new tool will appear in the Tools menu under "User-defined tools" (briefcase icon).

Add it to the menu bar using More Buttons/Customize Quick Access Toolbar > More Commands > Commands tab > User Tools, then drag and drop (if using the Ribbon), or Right-click on toolbar, Customize > Commands tab > User Tools (if using the classic toolbar).

[image: PL/SQL Developer Menu > More Buttons]

[image: PL/SQL Developer Menu > Customise]

Or if you prefer, follow the same steps to add a custom tool calling explorer.exe passing `#dir`, the directory path of the current editor file. Selecting this custom tool from the menu will open Windows Explorer at the current file's location.

More suggestions and screenshots here: https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/plsqldeveloper-setup-1.html#tools